# Get Kubernetes node status using Python Client API

Tags: python, pytest

Looking for some advice around how to get the status of a node using the Kubernetes client API for Python. I have the following:

```
print("| Node Status | Node Name |")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)

for a in ret.items:
        ret2 = v1.read_node_status(a.spec.node_name)
        rawData = (ret2.status.conditions)
```

However, ret2.status.conditions returns a malformed list/json object so it's proving difficult to search inside .conditions and retrieve the status and condition type. Has anyone written anything to retrieve the node status?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to my own question! Funny how the solution always comes when you think you're out of options!

```
nodeStatus = (node.status.conditions)

        for i in nodeStatus:
            status = i.status
            type = i.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and this gave me a hint today to write the following as I was looking for a complete solution.

```
config.load_kube_config()
kube_client = client.CoreV1Api()

node_list = kube_client.list_node(watch=False, pretty=True, limit=1000)
if len(node_list.items) > 0:
    print("NODE\t\t\t\t\t\tSTATUS")
    for node in node_list.items:
        node_name = node.metadata.name
        node_status = "Not Ready"   # Unknown, not ready, unhealthy, etc.
        node_scheduling = node.spec.unschedulable
        for condition in node.status.conditions:
            if condition.type == "Ready" and condition.status:
                node_status = "Ready"
                break
        if node_scheduling is None or not node_scheduling:
            print(f"{node_name} {node_status}")
        else:
            print(f"{node_name} {node_status},SchedulingDisabled")
else:
    print("No nodes available in the cluster")
```

and the output is,
[image: output]

References:

[K8S Node Conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition)

[Python Kube Client Object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1NodeCondition.md)